# CSS: make links inside text widget of same width as container

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

I've added some text links in a sidebar text widget at my wordpress site footer. Now I'm trying to make the text links have the same width as its div container. However, after trying hard the links remain with a smaller width.

The text I've added inside the text widget goes like this:

```
<p><a href="/contacto">Contacto</a></p>
<p><a href="/faqs">FAQs</a></p>
<p><a href="/politica-de-privacidad">Política de Privacidad</a></p>
<p><a href="/terminos-y-condiciones">Términos y Condiciones</a> </p>
```

And the general html structure is this:

[image]

Finally, the resulting footer links look like this:

[image]

I've tried to use:

```
display: inline-block; 
clear:both; 
float:left;`
```

at `#text-6.widget.widget_text`, but I get nothing. The `aside` label seems to be `display:block` by default.

Comment: Maybe trying making your menu an un-ordered list (ul)? and then remove the bullet points via css.

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Dont use inline block, just use: display:block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.widget a
{
display: block;
padding: 5px;
width: 100% //added for testing purposes
}
```

or

```
.textwidget a
{
display: block;
padding: 5px;
width: 100% //added for testing purposes
}
```

You can use !important as well if you want to overwrite all styles for the a tag.

I added the padding just as an example.

Comment: It seems that there is not a class such as .widget. I've tried with .textwidget and I don't get any result.

Comment: <aside id="text-6" class="widget widget_text">
Its right there, im taking the top level one, you can use any parent class that you would like to with the same result.

Comment: I think we might be confused here, do you want the element to extend or the text? Once you add the: "display:block;" and hover over the a tag, the entire line should be clickable, thus making it fill the width of its parent element. If you want the text to go to the end you can add: "text-align: justify;"

Comment: I need the text to have a width of 100% the container. Now I see that only when I use "display: block; width:300px;" I have a good result.